# fbprophet Exponential Growth

Tags: python, forecasting, facebook-prophet

So I currently have the following code where I am trying to forecast the number of electric vehicles miles in 30 years.

```
miles = [7851400, 22362800, 46612600, 78121800, 194901200, 416005800, 724719000, 1117932800, 1590637400, 2186914600]
years = []

for i in range(2010, 2020):
    years.append(i)
    
zipped_list = zip(years, miles)

EV_df = pd.DataFrame(list(zipped_list), columns = ['year', 'Electric Vehicles Miles'])
EV_df['year'] = pd.to_datetime(EV_df['year'], format='%Y')
EV_df[['y', 'ds']] = EV_df[['Electric Vehicles Miles', 'year']]
```

I then fit a prophet model and ask it to predict 30 years down the line.

```
ev_model = Prophet(weekly_seasonality=True)
ev_model.fit(EV_df)
future_electric = ev_model.make_future_dataframe(periods=30, freq='Y')
forecast_electric = ev_model.predict(future_electric)
```

However, the result is pretty much a linear trend where you can see how in the last 5 points it's starting to have some sort of exponential or massive increase in the number of miles which isn't really being recognized from the graph

[image]

How would I get it to recognize this spike and plot a smooth exponential graph and not assume it is linear?

Comment: From my understanding that is outside the scope of prophet that works well for seasonal data with linear or logistic trend. If you want to stick to prophet, what you could do is to take the logarithm of your data (miles) to linearize it. Fit the model on the logarithm and exponentiate the result. Otherwise you could directly fit an exponential function to your data?

Comment: This is a great idea actually. I might end up trying that. How would you go about exponentiating the result after prophet has calculated it? It's definitely a weird one to think about

Comment: Something like: miles_log = np.log(miles), then training the model and predicting pred_log. In the last step: pred = np.exp(pred)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also try changing your growth='linear parameter to growth='logistic' - which would handle exponetial or geometric growth. You would also need to add the saturation values if any.